# Wrap on Character is greyed out QGIS 2.12

Tags: qgis, labeling

In QGIS 2.12, my "Wrap on Character" option is greyed out. How do I make that active? 
With it unavailable, I cannot get multi line labels.

Comment: Do you have curve labels on?

Comment: Yep won't work for curved labels.

Answer (score 4):

Wrap on Character does not work if you have curved labels. In my case I am trying to label a road network and I have my labels curved and on the line so that the labels follow the path of the road.
Wrap on Character will only work if the labels are parallel to the line.

Answer (score 0):

An old question and a simple answer, but the problem can be avoided by changing the labels parallel and choosing the "wrap on character" option. After confirming it, change the labels back to curved, and the changes remain. Works at least in QGIS 2.16.